# what are the differences between src-min and src-min-noconflict in ace texteditor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to embed Ace text editor to my website from the prebuilt version:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/

However, I found two minified versions `src-min` and `src-min-noconflict` I know they're both minified versions but what are differences between them and which one I should use?

Comment: Actually no-conflict use the `ace.require` instead of only require.so, it won't conflict with your existing libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue (https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/584) is the reason there exists a `noconflict` version.

That issue also links to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/419 and https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/issues/47, where one reply says:

> noconflict was created as a workaround for the bug in dojo require ajaxorg/ace#584. the only difference is that it doesn't use global define

I do not understand the bugs of using a global define, but it sounds like using the `noconflict` version works around those bugs. I hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

As per the documentation:

> **src** concatenated but not minified
>   **src-min** concatenated and minified with uglify.js
>   **src-noconflict** uses ace.require instead of require

Here is the [link](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/)